# Reset row in listview Android

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview, row

In ListView, when i selected row it is set background color with reset previous selected one. but when listview scoll down it shows other row selected same backgound means one bye one page scroll down the row is selected.

Plz help me

In this two images i selected only first row but when i scroll the page 23 row is already selected. How to set selected row with scrollable page?

```
ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    lv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shape);

    // on seleting single voter
    // launching Edit Product Screen       

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        //mOnDoubleTapListener = listener;

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {

            boolean netFlag = new validationClass().haveNetworkConnection(context);

            if(!netFlag) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data Connection is not available.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }

            if (currentSelectedView != null && currentSelectedView != view) {
                TextView textViewName = (TextView) currentSelectedView.findViewById(R.id.name);
                TextView textViewPart = (TextView) currentSelectedView.findViewById(R.id.partno);
                textViewName.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.darker_gray));
                textViewPart.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.darker_gray));
            } currentSelectedView =view
                TextView textViewName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
                TextView textViewPart = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.partno);
                                textViewName.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.text_color));
                textViewPart.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.text_color));
            }
```

}

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, it's hard to follow your description without code samples. Please post snippets of code where you're having issues.

Comment: that's because ListView recycles views.
when you scroll your listview, the rows which go out of the screen are "cached" and then appear from the bottom as you scroll to the new rows.
try this for understanding: http://www.piwai.info/android-adapter-good-practices/#getView-recycling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two says to solve this:

1. A press/click on an item just sets the item as selected, and the user needs to click a button to act on the item.
2. Since your listview is fullscreen, have the onClick() record the position of the selected item.  On a subsequent click, compare the current position to the last.  If they aren't the same, just record the new position.  If they are the same, go ahead with the operation.  Or you could require the user to do a longclick (onItemLongClick()) to act on the selection if the current position is the same as the last.

Either way can help your app avoid detecting a click when the user is really trying to scroll.  Android won't call the onClick() if the user starts scrolling right away.  You can't control this.